# jQuery parsing RSS and namespaced element like <content:encoded>

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, parsing, encode

I am using jQuery to parse an RSS feed. Within each `<item>` is a namespaced element like `<content:encoded>` I want to select. How do I select it in jQuery?

```
$(xml).find('item') works but $(xml).find('item content') does not.
```

Comment: Could you post an example rss code and tell us which items you are trying to select?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451202/trying-to-get-contentencoded-with-jfeed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you loading the xml via Ajax? Then, make sure that the server sets the content type as 'text/xml' and not 'text/html'.

Also make sure that the tag name of the element you want is indeed content and not something else (like content:encoded). In that case try:

```
.find('item content\\:encoded')?
```

Special characters like : need to be escaped in jQuery selectors.

Comment: First thing I checked. It's feed.xml, so reading it as an XML file.

The issue is that the tag name is content:encoded.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this thread is fairly old but it is the first one that comes up in google when searching for this with jquery.  The easiest way to do the search is with:

```
.find('[nodeName="content:encoded"]')
```

Hope that helps someone.  I spent the last few hours trying to figure out a simple way to access those tags.

Comment: It's been a while but this worked out great form me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`.find('[nodeName="content:encoded"]')` it does works fine in Chrome and some older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from a search

> jQuery selectors are not
>   namespace-aware, so they only use
>   getElementsByTagName (rather than
>   getElementsByTagNameNS) to retrieve
>   elements by their nodeName attribute
>   (rather than by localName and
>   namespaceURI).

Looks like you need to do it in regular js by using the `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tagname)`