# Trying to get content:encoded with jfeed

Tags: jquery, rss, jfeed

I can get a successful response with the RSS I am trying to pull using jfeed, however, the thing I really want is the content. [content:encoded]  I need this so I can grab the first image from each post.

I figured it would be easy to update jfeed to do this, but nothing I try seems to get it.  The most obvious attempt was to add:

```
item.content = jQuery(this).find('content\:encoded').eq(0).text();
```

but this returns an empty string.  I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: Don't know jfeed, but I've used lots of feed parsers.

With that caveat, why do you prefix the colon with a slash? You should not need to do that.

Also, some feed parsers are not namespace aware. Since `content` is a namespace prefix, it's possible that jfeed is not able to `find()` on that. In that case, you would need to try `.find('encoded')`, omitting the namespace prefix.

It's also possible that that feed (or certain items in that feed) don't have the `content:encoded` element. That's an extension of RSS and not a required element.